# Unknown number of typehinted objects in Object Constructor

Tags: php

I'd like to pass multiple typehinted objects to object constructor.

I know it's possible to do __construct(...$data) but this expects array. I'd like to make sure that specified Interface is injected and do something like this __construct(...Interface $interface).

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for any help.